# Why does Lift and Drag calculation over an airfoil ignore shear stress?

Tags: aerodynamics

why in Lift and Drag calculation over an airfoil we ignore shear stress effect and focus on pressure distribution?

Comment: Shear stresses are important for drag. For lift their effect are two orders of magnitude smaller than pressure.

Answer (score 2):

We "Do" take viscous shear stresses into account when calculating the drag of an airfoil.
This is ALWAYS true for subsonic flows. The underlying reason behind this is called [D'Alembert's paradox](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node54.html). For incompressible and inviscid potential flow, the drag force is zero on a body moving with constant velocity relative to the fluid.

BOTH pressure drag and profile drag on an airfoil is viscous phenomena.

In order to provide a numerical example, please see the inviscid and viscous calculations of SD7037 airfoil. What you see in the inviscid case as drag, is merely a numerical error (- value).
[image] [image]

PS: In order to really understand how drag is formed, best to start looking up the ["Von Kármán Momentum Integral"](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node115.html) equation. Also to convince on the analytical results one can use [XFOIL](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/)'s VPlo menu under OPER and observe the momentum defect via delta* distribution and kinetic energy defect via CD distribution